# Program Analysis and Monotone Functions

Tags: compiler-construction, code-analysis, static-analysis

Could somebody explain the purpose of monotone functions when performing program analysis?

I am currently reading Hankin's "Principles of program analysis" but don't quite understand it's purpose.

By definition, a monotone function is any function such that for all elements x and y in set S, if x <= y => f(x) <= f(y).

Answer (score 1):

The [Knaster-Tarski fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem) says the following:

> Let L be a complete lattice and let f : L → L be an order-preserving function. Then the set of fixed points of f in L is also a complete lattice.

Because the set of fixed points of f in L are a complete lattice, there exists a least fixed point of f in L.  Additionally, there are potentially an infinite number of other fixed points.

Why do fixed points matter for program analysis?  If the lattice L is over abstract program states, a fixed point of the semantics of the loop, f, logically represents an inductive invariant or, in sets, represents a set of program states at a particular program location such that executing the program from that program location back to that same location starting from a state in that set of states, will produce a state within that set of states.  These state sets (or inductive invariants) are what abstract interpretation attempts to find.

For an intuitive description of abstract interpretation, I highly recommend the paper, Cousot, P. and Cousot, R.: [Static Determination of Dynamic Properties of Programs](http://www.di.ens.fr/~cousot/COUSOTpapers/ISOP76.shtml); ISOP 1976.  It predates the "famous" [Cousot and Cousot '77](http://www.di.ens.fr/~cousot/COUSOTpapers/POPL77.shtml) paper, but is somewhat less mired in advanced mathematics.